# Interactive heatmap changing it rows and columns with animation

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, r-highcharter, d3heatmap, heatmaply

I want to make a heatmap looks like this one in d3 package in javascript, Is that available in R ? i searched for many packages in `htmlwidgets` but i couldn't find a package do this graph.
Help please.

http://bl.ocks.org/ianyfchang/8119685

Comment: Can't you just replace the data in the code that you referenced?

Comment: i dont know how to use javascript codes, if you know away to do that, it would be a great help. i want to use the code and manipulate it with shiny and render it on shiny.

Comment: I don't know javascript either, however, counting 1+1 together one should be able to replace the labels and the data in the source code provided on the referenced site.

Answer (score 1):

This type of interactivity is not currently possible in any R packages of which I am aware. You would have to [create your own `htmlwidget`](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html) by adapting the linked code.